# iOS app shows 1 rep (and 0 badges) on the Main Sites sidebar even though this user has 101 (and 2 badges)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, ios-app

As you can see in the image, the reputation of user anongoodnurse/medica [on Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/1028/medica) is 1, not 101 as usual. I don't know this is a bug or not, so I just posted it here. I haven't checked their account on web.

[image: iOS bug]

It might be worth mentioning that even the badges are not shown here - but they are on the right pane.

**Update:** it's back to normal now. Maybe because of the new version of the app?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me - it says 101 on the right pane in your screenshot (and [on the web](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/1028/medica)) - the only place it says 1 is in the left sidebar. Don't know why...

Comment: In the Android App the reputation [appears correctly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vyVkF.png).

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ no problem. It's just my taste. Anyway, thank you for improve my post. It's hard to write a quality one with links when you are on iPad

Comment: I just checked and it looks correct on my app. Are you still seeing it?  Could have been something self correcting on the server.

Comment: @Brian maybe difference between iPad and non-iPad version?

Comment: @anangle-bracketedarachnid I wonder why you change the tense of the word `post` from present to past?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this issue on the production or beta apps on iPhone and iPad, or by running the query [`/2.2/users/3674367/associated?page=1&pagesize=100&types=main_site;meta_site`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=1&pagesize=100&ids=3674367&types=main_site%3Bmeta_site&filter=default&run=true).

I haven't asked around and I am not a core developer but I would venture a guess that some query or API call was run and cached between when the account was created and when the rep bonus was applied.  Then three days later you were the first person to hit that code path and it returned that stale data before reloading.  I'll ping Kevin about it but since this resolved itself and doesn't appear to be hurting anyone, I'm not super worried about it.